# Correct orientation of EMI filter

Tags: identification, components

The label of this EMI filter seems reversed to me because in the diagram there are three pins on the side of the line but the are two wires on that side of the device.

[image: CW1B-10A-L]

Is there a way to determine the correct orientation? I did some tests with a LCR meter but I measured around 100 nF on both sides trying different frequencies.

Comment: Did you buy it from a reputable source? If you did then you are quite within your right to ask for an explanation from them and expect to have the details covered in a pdf data sheet. If you didn't then, maybe you can't really trust anything on the diagram.

Comment: @Andyaka I bought it on Amazon a couple of years ago...

Comment: Someone in china probably just stuck the sticker on wrong. Check resistances at steady state for all wires to case and to green. (Don't forget green to case)

Comment: @Abel Blue or brown to case or green gives OL. Blue to brown gives 1 MOhm, green to case 0.05 Ohm.

Comment: I should have explained- the purpose of the resistance check is to differentiate the two blue from one another (or the two brown from one another). Since route to green/case is OL ground is tied purely via the caps, but protection mechanism (that 1M) is built between blue and brown. That mechanism should be on the load side. You can try all 12 permutations (depending on what's used and your meter's resistance measurement implementation, high side may matter) of the 4 blue left, blue right, brown left, brown right and should be able to locate where it lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The schematic on the label has the load on the two-wire side, so yes, somebody stuck the label on backwards.

Comment: That is what I was thinking but it was also wondering if there is a simple method to prove it.

Comment: In practice, it really doesn't matter that much. The attenuation characteristics of the filter in either direction are pretty much identical. The ground lead is normally placed on the input side so that it can be attached to the same chassis lug that the ground lead from the line cord attaches to.

Comment: What about safety? Usually I see CY caps on the load side.

Comment: Class-X and class-Y capacitors work the way they're supposed to either way. The inductors do not materially affect that.